# mysql - How to retrieve all the attributes of the group and to take attribute values for a given product that is associated with the group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to retrieve all the attributes of the group  for eg. WHERE idGroup = '2' AND idLanguage = '1'
and then get **attrValue if exist** for some **product** WHERE eg. group = '2'; **if not exist** print **attrValue** = ''

---

e.g.

### my tables

**table: products**

- idProduct
- idGroup

**table: products_attributes**

- idProduct
- idAttr
- idLanguage
- attrValue

**table: attributes**

- idAttr
- nameAttr
- idLanguage

**table: groups_attributes**

- idGroup
- idAttr

---

*with this query*

```
SELECT a.idAttr, a.nameAttr
FROM attributes  AS a
INNER JOIN groups_attributes AS ga ON a.idAttr= ga.idAttr
WHERE ga.idGroup = 1 AND ga.idLanguage = eng
```

*result is*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [idAttr] => 1
            [idGroup] => 1
            [nameAttr] => color
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [idAttr] => 2
            [idGroup] => 1
            [nameAttr] => height
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [idAttr] => 3
            [idGroup] => 1
            [nameAttr] => width
        )
)
```

**how** to join table **products_attributes** to get result like this ??

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [idAttr] => 1
            [idGroup] => 1
            [nameAttr] => color
            [idProduct] => 1
            [valueAttr] => NULL or ''
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [idAttr] => 2
            [idGroup] => 1
            [nameAttr] => height
            [idProduct] => 1
            [valueAttr] => 1600
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [idAttr] => 3
            [idGroup] => 1
            [nameAttr] => width
            [idProduct] => 1
            [valueAttr] => 900
        )
)
```

I save attributes for the product only whan value of attribute is set (in this eg. attribute `color` is not set for product `idProduct=1`)

When edit product data, **how** to retrieve all the attributes of the group and to take attribute values ​​for a given product that is associated with the group ?

Answer (score 0):

try with left outer join and case statement as below (you have to make sure you proper join condition between your tables). I have not included products table in the join, but if you want to join on products too you left outer join it too.

```
SELECT a.idAttr, a.nameAttr, case when pa.idProduct is not null then pa.attrValue else "" end
FROM attributes  AS a
INNER JOIN groups_attributes AS ga ON a.idAttr= ga.idAttr
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_attributes AS pa ON a.idAttr=pa.idAttr
WHERE ga.idGroup = 1 AND ga.idLanguage = eng
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query with Products joined, if you want '' instead of null use `coalesce(pa.attrValue, '') as attrValue` in place of `pa.attrValue`

```
SELECT a.idAttr, ga.idGroup, a.nameAttr, p.idProduct, pa.attrValue
FROM attributes  AS a
INNER JOIN groups_attributes AS ga ON a.idAttr= ga.idAttr
INNER JOIN products AS p ON ga.idGroup = p.idGroup
LEFT JOIN products_attributes pa ON p.idProduct = pa.idProduct AND pa.idAttr = a.idAttr and pa.idLanguage = ga.idLanguage 
WHERE ga.idGroup = 1 AND ga.idLanguage = eng
```